# Use Bundle-NativeCode on Linux does not work

Tags: java, linux, eclipse-plugin, shared-libraries, bundle

I create a plugin which includes the following folder structure:

- src
- native/so/libsystemcommand.so
- META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

The manifest include the command

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Commands Plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: de.system.commands;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: de.system.commands.CommandsPlugin
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Bundle-NativeCode: native/so/libsystemcommand.so; osname = Linux; processor = x86
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.apache.commons.logging
Eclipse-AutoStart: true
Export-Package: de.system.commands,
 de.system.commands.jni,
 de.system.commands.utils
Bundle-ClassPath: .
```

The build.properties looks like

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               native/
```

In the start method of my `Activator` class I call

```
System.loadLibrary("systemcommand");
```

At runtime the library is not found and a **UnsatisfiedLinkError** is thrown.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libsystemcommand in java.library.path
```

Do I have to set more attributes in the plugin? Do I have to unzip some informations on the target platform?

**EDIT:**

```
java.library.path=/opt/jdk/j2re1.4.2_16/lib/i386/client:/opt/jdk/j2re1.4.2_16/lib/i386:/opt/jdk/j2re1.4.2_16/../lib/i386::/opt/dsa/lib:/opt/dsa/lib
```

Comment: what do you have in your java.library.path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the solution.

We only build the plugin which was not working and copy it to the destination platform directory. After this we start the application as wtach the log files whether the library was foud or not.

What we miss, was to **delete the configurations folder**. The new plugin was not unzipp and the library was not existing in the configurations directory.

Im sorry and thank you for your answers.

**EDIT :**

The configuration folder is placed at

```
<installation>/eclipse/configuration/
```

At least delete everything without the file

```
<installation>/eclipse/configuration/config.ini
```

Comment: @Markus Lausberg -- I think I'm having the same problem but I don't understand what you mean be "delete the configurations folder". Where is it and how does one go about deleting it?

Comment: I enhanced my answer and printed the configuration folder path into

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if the library needs to be specified without the lib prefix?  E.g.,

```
System.loadLibrary("systemcommand");
```

Since that is how the library would be passed on a gcc link line.

Comment: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/runerrormessages.html#UNSATISFIEDLINKERROR suggests that the opposite (add the .so suffix) is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

The lib has to be in your filesystem (not in an archive file). 
Then you can either use the linux environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` pointing to the lib or define the property java.library.path

Comment: i expect, that the plugin would do this fopr me, because on Windows platforms this is working without additional library path.

Comment: @flolo - you are mistaken; the Eclipse framework supports loading native libraries from plugin bundles (JAR files).

Answer (score 1):

In a plugin fragment for linux, I use:

```
Bundle-NativeCode: librptlc.so; osname = linux; processor=x86
```

And in the main plugin I use:

```
if (OS.equals(Platform.OS_LINUX)) {
    System.loadLibrary("rptlc");
}
```

This should work within one plugin too.

I seem to remember having some problems with libraries in a sub folder in the jar, but I'm not sure why this would be the case. I just stuck to having the libraries in the root of a plugin fragment instead, which works for me.

You could also try getting the file system path of the library (not sure if that's easy) and loading it using:

```
libraryPath = "C:\eclipse\bundles\123\librptlc.so";
System.load(libraryPath);
```